# UDP Tracker only gives me my ip as answer to announce request

Tags: python, udp, tracker, torrent

I've recently been trying to create a torrent client in python, and have just got the UDP announce protocol to work.
The tracker accepts my connect request just fine but only returns my IP and port as the peer list when I announce to it...
I've tried to look at the same torrents in other torrent clients and they have multiple working peers while my request only shows me my computer (I've tried this on many torrents, all return just my IP and port)

Here's the code for the sending function itself:

```
    async def announce_udp(self, try_num = 1):
    self.sock.settimeout(15)
    answer = {}
    inner_while = False
    while try_num < 4:
        while try_num < 4:
            try:
                print("trying to send")
                sended = self.send(1, self.announce_payload())
                print("sending the following packet: {0}".format(sended))
                print(self.url)
                inner_while = True
                break
            except Exception:
                print("problem in sending")
                try_num += 1
        if not inner_while:
            break
        try:
            answer = self.interpret(15)
            break
        except Exception:
            print("problem in receiving")
            try_num += 1
    print("announce answer is: {0}".format(answer))
    return answer
```

here's the code for the make payload function:

```
def announce_payload(self, downloaded = 0, left = 0, uploaded = 0, event = 0, key = get_transaction_id()):
    payload = [self.torrent.get_torrent_info_hash_decoded(), get_peer_id().encode(), downloaded,
               self.torrent.get_torrent_size(), uploaded, event, 0, key, -1, 6988]
    p_tosend = None
    try:
        p_tosend = struct.pack('!20s20sqqqiIIiH', *payload)
    except Exception as e:
        print("there was an error: {0}".format(e))
    return p_tosend
```

here's the code for the interpret + process function:

```
def interpret(self, timeout=10):
    self.sock.settimeout(timeout)
    print("got to interpret")
    try:
        response = self.sock.recv(10240)
        print("answer recieved")
    except socket.timeout:
        print("no answer, try again")
        raise TrackerResponseException("no answer", 0)

    headers = response[:8]
    payload = response[8:]

    action, trans_id = struct.unpack('!ll', headers)

    try:
        trans = self.transactions[trans_id]
    except KeyError:
        raise TrackerResponseException("InvalidTransaction: id not found", trans_id)

    try:
        trans['response'] = self.process(action, payload, trans)
    except Exception as e:
        trans['response'] = None
        print("error occured: {0}".format(e))
    trans['completed'] = True
    del self.transactions[trans_id]
    #print(trans)
    return trans

  def process_announce(self, payload, trans):
    response = {}
    info = payload[:struct.calcsize("!lll")]
    interval, leechers, seeders = struct.unpack("!lll", info)
    print(interval, leechers, seeders, "noamsssssss")
    peer_data = payload[struct.calcsize("!lll"):]
    peer_size = struct.calcsize("!lH")
    num_of_peers = int(len(peer_data) / peer_size)
    print("the number of peers is: {0} and the peer data is: {1}".format(num_of_peers, peer_data))
    print()
    peers = []
    for peer_offset in range(num_of_peers):
        off = peer_size * peer_offset
        peer = peer_data[off:off + peer_size]
        addr, port = struct.unpack("!lH", peer)
        peers.append({
            'addr': socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', addr)),
            'port': port,
        })
    print(payload)
    return dict(interval=interval, leechers=leechers, seeders=seeders, peers=peers)
```

I'm sorry if any of this is irrelevant, but I want to give you all of the code incase it tells you something.

(get_peer_id() returns a random peer id per the tracker protocol specification, and the get_transaction_id() returns random.randint(0, 1 << 32 - 1))

EDIT:
Alright, I've found the problem and now I'm feeling pretty dumb...
turns out even in the udp tracker whenever you send the info hash it has to be SHA1 encoded.
Hopefully this can help someone if they are stuck in the same problem :)

Comment: This does not look like the connect announce call and response pattern described in the [BEP](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html).  I'd expect to see the connect call and response followed by the announce call and response.  Is there missing code?

Comment: @AnonCoward I did not add the connect method because it works just fine, my problem is when I announce after I connected it returns only 1 peer, which is always me... (if I need to upload it I will I just don't see the need as the connect interaction with the tracker works fine)
as for the BEP protocol, I do not send on the exact same time frame they specify there but other than that the message is built per specification using the struct module to build it.

Comment: Then you don't have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  My point being, the BEP in question uses the response from the connect message to feed into the announce message, which I don't see you doing, and since your solution isn't reproducible by others, no one can really tell you why it's failing beyond guesses.

Comment: @AnonCoward I've just found the problem, the info hash was not sha1 encoded....
Anyways, thanks for your time! This is my first question on StackOverflow so I'm sorry that I did not give you everything you needed. I'll make sure to read what you've linked and make the next question easier to follow :)

Comment: Glad you found the solution!  Feel free to follow up with your solution to your own post, in case others stumble across the same issue.